# How to use FOR loop to sorting list in Robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework, want to verify Web-elements from web page are arranged in ascending order in web-table.

Below are the Web Table sample data which Need to verify that It is present in Ascending order:

```
Amoxicil + Clavula Ac 625mg Tablet
Ceaxone Intion 1g 5s
Masuscitation Silicone Large
Gauerile Swab 12ply 5x5cm, 
Hydrocortisone 1% 15g
```

Using java it is very simple I converted these strings into hashcode() values then compare these hashcode() values with each others.

For example :

Hashcode() value of String "Amoxicil + Clavula Ac 625mg Tablet" should be less than Hashcode() value of String " Ceaxone Intion 1g 5s"

Below is java code for the same :

```
public boolean Sorting(String field) {
    List<WebElement> objs = driver.findElements(By.xpath(field));
    for (int i = 0; i < objs.size() - 1; i++) {
        objs.get(i).toString().hashCode();
        if ((objs.get(i).toString().hashCode()) <= (objs.get(i + 1).toString().hashCode())) {
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

from  last 2 days i am working on, to implement same logic using Robot Framework. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pass the data as a list and use the keyword Sort List of Collections library:

Example:

```
*** Setting ***
Library    Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Sort List Test
${list}    Create List    Amoxicil + Clavula Ac 625mg Tablet
...    Ceaxone Intion 1g 5s
...    Masuscitation Silicone Large
...    Gauerile Swab 12ply 5x5cm, 
...    Hydrocortisone 1% 15g
Sort List    ${list}
:FOR     ${element}    IN    ${list}
\\     Do your stuff
```